# Can you intercept and create a AxiosPromise within a function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, axios

I want to change a function that returns an AxiosPromise that currently works like so:

```
example(){
 return api.get(url);
}
```

Where api.get returns an object of type `AxiosPromise<any>`

To something like this, where I can modify the object the original promise resolves:

```
example(){
 if(condition){
  newPromise = new AxiosPromise<any>((res, rej) => {
   api.get(url).then( x => {
     x.data = 3;
     res(x);
    }
   };
  return newPromise;
 } else return api.get(url);
}
```

This example is based on my knowledge on how you use the normal Promise object but from what I can see AxiosPromise can't be used in this way.

Goal is to be able to modify the response if the condition is true but not have to refactor everywhere the function is currently being used.

Comment: How do you resolve that `AxiosPromise` when you call the function? Is it as simple as `example().then(response => console.log(response.data))`?

Comment: @codemonkey, I believe for the most part that I can see yes. (Codebase is quite large and has been worked on a couple people before me). Right now I am actually using the code above but with a regular promise instead of axiosPromise and don't see any problems in the program but for the sake of maintaining types and avoiding unforeseen sideffects, I thought I would drop this stackoverflow question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion isn't wholly dissimilar to what you're already doing. You're using a regular promise now and my solution involves it as well. The *unforeseen side effects* you mention aren't likely to spring from the type of promise you return, but rather from what that promise resolves to i.e. (axios response object). So long as you keep it intact, I doubt all those other calls to your function will have any issues. As such, here is how I would modify your `example` function. In its original it looks like so:

```
example(){
   return api.get(url);
}
```

And here is how you call it:

```
example().then(({data}) => console.log(data))
```

Ok. So far so good, but for starters I would wrap your axios call into a regular promise:

```
example(){
   return Promise.resolve(axios.get(url).then(response => response))
}
```

This change does not change a thing on the caller side. You would still call it like so:

```
example().then(({data}) => console.log(data))
```

Now you want to add a condition to the function that, if true, modifies the response in some way. So here it is:

```
example(condition){
   return Promise.resolve(axios.get(url).then(response => {
      if(condition === true)  response.data.somekey = 'Changed';
      return response; //The response object is intact save for the one change.
   }))
}
```